# A popup menu that is linked to a uitable that changes with each option on the popup menu (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, menu, popup, matlab-uitable

I've created GUI that has a popup menu with several options (mouse 1 - mouse 10) in it to choose from, and also created a uitable next to it. The popup menu has several options to choose from.

I want to link between the popup menu and the uitable so that each mouse that the user chooses - a new uitable will replace the previous uitable of the previous mouse.

How do I do that?

Here is the relevant code, which is nothing, really:

```
function mouse_number_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)


function uitable1_CellEditCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what code you have thus far?

Comment: As you said, the code you posted shows nothing. Please include _more_ relevant code (what's inside the `mouse_number_Callback` function for example) and don't forget to use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've properly understood what did you menan with

> each mouse that the user chooses - a new uitable will replace the previous uitable of the previous mouse

and, in turn, the expected behaviour of the GUI.

I've set up a simple GUI containing a `table` (`tag: uitable1`) and a `popupmenu` (`tag: popupmenu1`).

When the user selects an item in a `popupmenu`, in the corresponding row of `table` the string *Selected*

- In the `uitable1_CreateFcn` the content of the `table` is set to empty strings
- In the `popupmenu1_Callback` the index of the item selected in the `popoumenu` is identified and, in the corresponding row of the table, the string *Selected* is printed and the previous one deleted.

This is the code of the GUI

```
function varargout = table_gui(varargin)
% TABLE_GUI MATLAB code for table_gui.fig
%      TABLE_GUI, by itself, creates a new TABLE_GUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = TABLE_GUI returns the handle to a new TABLE_GUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      TABLE_GUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in TABLE_GUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      TABLE_GUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new TABLE_GUI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before table_gui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to table_gui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help table_gui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 20-Aug-2015 17:31:24

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @table_gui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @table_gui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before table_gui is made visible.
function table_gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to table_gui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for table_gui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes table_gui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = table_gui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on selection change in popupmenu1.
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to popupmenu1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns popupmenu1 contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from popupmenu1

% Get the index of the selected popupmenu item
sel_m=get(hObject,'value')
% Clear table content
for i=1:10
   sel_sts{i,1}='      ';
end
% If "--- Select a Mouse ---" has been selected then set table with empty
% string
if(sel_m == 1)
   set(handles.uitable1,'data',sel_sts)
else
% If a "Mouse" has been selected then set "Selected" in the corresponding
% cell of the table
   sel_sts{sel_m - 1,1}='Selected';
   set(handles.uitable1,'data',sel_sts)
end

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to popupmenu1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: popupmenu controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function uitable1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to uitable1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Initialize table content with empty string
for i=1:10
   sel_sts{i,1}='      ';
end
set(hObject,'data',sel_sts);
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! What a detailed answer! So first of all, thank you so much for investing so much in my answer.

This almost gets what I wanted: The popup menu is exactly as I wanted it, but the table is supposed to be a totally new table for each mouse, and not just a different row for each mouse.

I mean that I collect data and fill a whole table for each mouse separately. However, your code has all that I need anyway, so I'll just modify it a little bit.

Thanks a lot again, this was really helpful!

Yotam

Comment: Your're welcome! Actually it was not clear to me what did you mean with "new table". Perhaps you might want to "accept" the answer :-)